# Wordpress wp_get_post_terms function wont work in template

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I have made a function using wp_get_post_terms

```
function subcategory() {
$args = array(
    "fields" => "all",
    'taxonomy' => 'videos_category',
    'orderby'           => 'ID',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
);
$categories = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'videos_category', $args);

if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    echo $categories[0]->name;  
}}
```

And using Laravel blade templating I call the function like so:

```
            @if( App\subcategory() )
                <li class="pill-list__pill--accent">
                    <span>{{ App\subcategory() }}</span>
                </li>
            @endif
```

I'm using a namespace App, hence the App..
The code I have below works fine if I have it in the template itself using Php tags... not sure why I can't call it in a function though.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blade's `{{ }}` is shorthand for `echo`.  So whatever is inside there should be a variable that is a string or a function which returns a string.  Your function actually `echo`s.  So inside PHP tags it would work, but not in Blade echo tags.

Change your function to return your string, not echo it:

```
return $categories[0]->name;
```